# How to send data to server and receive response in same methood

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im new to ios i have a doubt that i want to send data to server and receive response in same method

i have a class name
profile.m and i want to send data to service class and receive response in profile class

**Profile.m:**

```
NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@&lksite=social&lkmenu=profile&lktype=view&displayedname=%@&displayid=%@", baseUrl, accessToken, userName,userId];

Service *service = [[Service alloc]init];
   [service sendDataToServer:@"POST" andUrl:parameter andUrl:baseUrl];
```

**Service.m**

```
-(void) sendDataToServer:(NSString *) method andUrl:(NSString *) getUrl andUrl:(NSString *)baseUrl{
NSMutableData *jsondata;
Session *ses =[[Session alloc]init];
accessToken = [ses getAccessToken];
NSLog(@"Access Token---> %@",accessToken);

NSString *baseUrl1 = [NSString baseUrl];


if([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]){
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@&access_token=%@",getUrl,accessToken];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlStr];
    urlRequest=  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    urlRequest.HTTPMethod=method;
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    if( connection )
    {
        urlMutable = [NSMutableData new];
    }
}else{
    NSData *parameterData = [getUrl dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString: baseUrl1];
    urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    urlRequest.HTTPBody=parameterData;
    urlRequest.HTTPMethod=method;
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    if( connection )
    {
        urlMutable = [NSMutableData new];
    }
}}
```

Comment: Just use completion handler with block, first one for success, second for failure request

Answer (score 1):

You can user `NSLocalNotification` to achieve your task.
There are three simple steps to use `NSLocalNotification`.

1) For this you can write your code in `Profile.m` file as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

Service *Service = [[Service alloc] init];
        [Service sendDataToServer:(with your parameters here)];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(responceMethod:) name:@"WebServiceCall" object:nil];
}
```

2) in your Service.m class make a service call

```
    -(void) sendDataToServer:(NSString *) method andUrl:(NSString *) getUrl andUrl:(NSString *)baseUrl{
    NSMutableData *jsondata;
    Session *ses =[[Session alloc]init];
    accessToken = [ses getAccessToken];
    NSLog(@"Access Token---> %@",accessToken);

    NSString *baseUrl1 = [NSString baseUrl];


    if([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]){
        NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@&access_token=%@",getUrl,accessToken];
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlStr];
        urlRequest=  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod=method;
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        if( connection )
        {
            urlMutable = [NSMutableData new];
        }
    }else{
        NSData *parameterData = [getUrl dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: baseUrl1];
        urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        urlRequest.HTTPBody=parameterData;
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod=method;
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        if( connection )
        {
            urlMutable = [NSMutableData new];
        }
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    int errorCode = (int)httpResponse.statusCode;
    NSLog(@"response is %d", errorCode);

    [urlMutable setLength: 0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [urlMutable appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;
    id *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"WebServiceCall" object:nil userInfo:response];
}
```

And finally 
3) Implement your response parsing here in the method you have written in `Profile.m` file like:

```
-(void)responceMethod:(NSNotification *)notif{
NSDictionary *dict = [notif userInfo];
// Your response parsing.
}
```

Comment: It must be comment, Do not post it as answer. Please read the documentation for the same.

Comment: @Abizern I am unable to understand your question

Comment: It wasn't a question. Most people have moved on to using NSURLSession.

Comment: @Abizern Thank you brother, But considering his question, I though that he might be a learner. And I though He is comfortable with NSURLConnection. Thats why I have not suggested him to go with NSURLSession. I hope you understand...!!!

Answer (score -1):

Declare a block as :

```
typedef void (^completionBlock)(id responseObject , NSError *error);
```

And then add this block to your methods as :

```
- (void) performRequestWithCompletion:(completionBlock)block;
```

On invoking this method, will return you "responseObject" and "error". error nil in case of success